# Ubuntu 18.04 boots to blank purple screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04, gpu

My first install of Ubuntu was 16.04 with the only problems being with Ubuntu not wanting to play nice with my Nvidia graphics card. I later upgraded to 17.10 with no problems. I just now upgraded to 18.04. All appeared to go fine until the upgrade process finished and it asked to restart. I said okay. The system then rebooted to a blank purple screen.

If I forcibly power down and then turn power on I get to a grub menu. I can get in if I select an alternate boot option but when I shut down, the next time I boot up I'm right back at the blank purple screen.

On one of these alternate boots, I went in to XDiagnostics and turned on the options for extra debug logging and turned off the bootloader graphics. I can now see that Ubuntu apparently goes into an infinite hang on "a start job is running for detect the available gpus and deal with any system changes"

Is there a definitive fix for this?

If there is not a fix for this then how can I downgrade the install (without loss of data) to 17.10 which worked just fine?

Thanks.

Comment: Seem like this might be the same issue as inscribed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036406/ubuntu-18-04-blank-screen-on-booting

Comment: Similar but not the same.  Searching tells me this is a wide spread problem that really needs to be addressed. I find it surprising that  this error is happening since my Nvidia card is 4 years old and Nvidia is a key player in the GPU market.

Answer (score 2):

Given that downgrading is not an option and given that I would prefer not to have to reinstall Ubuntu and then reinstall and reconfigure all the apps I've already set up, as a work around I am going to use the following solution which works for me:

1. Press right shift key when booting up.
2. When the Grub menu appears, select "advanced options for Ubuntu" and press enter.
3. Select "Ubuntu with Linux 4.13.0-41-generic" and press enter.
4. Log in.

It seems that the problem is with the 4.15 kernel and since I can't undo the upgrade from 17.1 to 18.04, I can use this method to fall back to the 4.13 kernel.

Is it a kludge? Yes. But one that is certainly preferable to a complete re-install.