# Ubuntu 18.04 , blank screen on booting

Tags: 18.04

While starting the system, it asks for password and getting the password it takes me to a blank screen. Then I press the power button to turn it off and restart it. Sometimes it works, else it continues with the above problem.

Comment: I had this problem as well, on an older version of ubuntu though, but let me ask this; did you try a different monitor?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is the password in question for your user account or to decrypt the drive with the Ubuntu installation? What's the last thing you see on the screen before the password entry dialogue?

Comment: I have the same issue on a fresh install of 18.04. I can only log in when I switch to "Ubuntu on Wayland" via the cog icon on the bottom right of the password field. 

When I try to log into the standard Gnome environment I get the blank screen with only a cursor.

Comment: @delfiler , no I didn't.  I was talking about my laptop.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, The password for the user account. Everything is normal and usual. The screen has the UBUNTU logo and from there it takes me to the password dialog box.

Comment: @dhuyvetter. Yes. Something similar happens with my case as well.

Comment: @HarshadKESHWANI still worth trying if you were to ask me cause thanks to trying a different monitor we were able to fix the problem and now we can use any monitor we like, our problem was that certain screen resolutions weren't supported or put in for that matter

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem (mine was after I upgraded to kubuntu 18.04 from 16.04) here was my fix:

I used ssh to log into my pc remotely (you may have trouble here-sorry) then turned off the X desktop.

```
$ sudo systemctrl stop display-manager
```

After that, I installed the nvidia driver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
```

Reboot and it seemed to work.  Hope that helps someone.